# Creating Custom Regristration in SIlverlight Business Application

Tags: silverlight, service, ria

I need to customize the default registration page in Silverlight Business template using my own SQL Server database and table fields. Same for login. How do I do this? Any good idea or documentation is higly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this article will help you.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83078/A-Sample-Silverlight-4-Application-Using-MEF-MVVM